# Add different sounds to different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventhandler

I am working through a project using Javascript and jQuery. The projects requires me to add sounds to buttons. A different sound should play depending on the button I click. I know how to add a single audio file to buttons, but can someone help me with adding different audio to each button?

```
$(".btn").on("click" , function () {
    let buttonSound = $(this).attr("id");
    playSound(buttonSound);

});
```

My project gives a random color, which corresponds with a button. This code works to play the sound of that button, but it also plays that sound with my other buttons (instead of the sound they are suppose to play). The only way to change the sound is to refresh the screen, but this has the same issue, just with a different random button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.btn` is indeed a too common selector to do something that specific.
Instead you could try this better strategy, and that's by using the [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) like:

```html
<button class="btn" data-sound="cat" type="button">Cat</button>
<button class="btn" data-sound="dog" type="button">Dog</button>
```

and then in jQuery:

```js
$("[data-sound]").on("click", function() {
  const buttonSound = $(this).data("sound");
  playSound(buttonSound);
});
```

or in pure JavaScript if you prefer:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-sound]").forEach((elBtn) => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    playSound(elBtn.dataset.sound);
  });
});
```

this way you get rid of ID selectors, and if needed you can have more than one button that plays the same sound - without running into issues related to duplicated IDs.
Always use the **data attribute** when in need to store and retrieve arbitrary data in HTML.

PS:
Since you did not provided any code for the `playSound` function, for any future reader to this question, the above code is meant to work given a function like:

```js
const playSound = (fileName) => {
  const audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = `path/to/your/audio/${fileName}.mp3`;
  audio.play();
};
```

with no need to mention that you need to adjust the relative path  `path/to/your/audio/` to the desired directory where you have all our audio files. Well, unless you have in the `data-audio=""` the full path with filename and extension like `data-audo="drumset/crash.mp3"` in which case you would need only `audio.src = fileName;` or rather `audio.src = pathToFile;`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion but it didn't seem to work for me. What ended up working was this: 

$("#red").click(function(){
    let audio = $("audio")[0];
    audio.play();
});

I repeated it for the four color buttons that I have. This is obviously long code, any suggestions for optimizing it?

Comment: @LeslieW. (you're very welcome) Yes you can optimize it in the same fashion. All you need to do is, understand the provided code (ask me it something is not clear, or if you have errors in the console), and implement it into your project as suggested. That is my best knowledgeable suggestion I can give you from my expertise.  Don't use IDs like `"#red"`. Don't use IDs at all. Store the audio file name in the `data-sound` attribute and add the extension later (like `".mp3"`) any play it. You gave no code for the `playSound` function. Do you want me to provide that one too?

Comment: Thank you, you are a life saver. My playSound() was the most convoluted mess of if/else if/else. It worked, but obviously not the best. This is much better code, and makes so much more sense.

Comment: @LeslieW glad it's working now. Happy coding